# Build PGF/TikZ matrix from CSV file

Tags: tikz-pgf, csv, csvsimple

I want to automatically build a PGF/TikZ based drawing based on some external data that is read using `csvsimple`. My main issue at the moment is that most of the nodes are part of a matrix, mainly to setup a consistent spacing. Asssembling the contents of `\matrix{csv-stuff-goes-here}` didn't get me very far, so I tried to use `\NewEnviron` to define a custom matrix environment. The first examples looked promising:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

% working example
\begin{tikzpicture}[every matrix/.style = {column sep = 0.8 cm, row sep = 0.2 cm}]
  \matrix{
    \draw (0,0) circle (4mm); & \node (n1) {Hello}; \\
    \draw (0,0) circle (2mm); & \node (n2) {world}; \\
  };
  \draw[thick, draw=black] (n1) -- (n2);
\end{tikzpicture}

% this works as well
\NewEnviron{TheMatrix}{\matrix[ampersand replacement=\&]{\BODY};}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every matrix/.style = {column sep = 0.8 cm, row sep = 0.2 cm}]
  \begin{TheMatrix}
    \draw (0,0) circle (4mm); \& \node (n1) {Hello}; \\        
    \draw (0,0) circle (2mm); \& \node (n2) {world}; \\        
  \end{TheMatrix} 
  \draw[thick, draw=black] (n1) -- (n2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Now I wanted to introduce the `csvsimple` package - and failed miserably. MNWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{filecontents*}{mystuff.csv}
mynode;mytext
n1;Hello
n2;World
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

% working example
\begin{tikzpicture}[every matrix/.style = {column sep = 0.8 cm, row sep = 0.2 cm}]
  \matrix{
    \draw (0,0) circle (4mm); & \node (n1) {Hello}; \\
    \draw (0,0) circle (2mm); & \node (n2) {world}; \\
  };
  \draw[thick, draw=black] (n1) -- (n2);
\end{tikzpicture}

% this works as well
\NewEnviron{TheMatrix}{\matrix[ampersand replacement=\&]{\BODY};}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every matrix/.style = {column sep = 0.8 cm, row sep = 0.2 cm}]
  \begin{TheMatrix}
    \draw (0,0) circle (4mm); \& \node (n1) {Hello}; \\        
    \draw (0,0) circle (2mm); \& \node (n2) {world}; \\        
  \end{TheMatrix} 
  \draw[thick, draw=black] (n1) -- (n2);
\end{tikzpicture}

% now let's try it from a CSV file
\begin{tikzpicture}[every matrix/.style = {column sep = 0.8 cm, row sep = 0.2 cm}]
  \begin{TheMatrix}
    \csvreader[separator = semicolon, head to column names]{mystuff.csv}{}{
      \draw (0,0) circle (4mm); \& \node (\mynode) {\mytext}; \\        
    }
  \end{TheMatrix} 
  \draw[thick, draw=black] (n1) -- (n2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The reported error is

```
pdflatex.exe> ! Missing } inserted.
pdflatex.exe> <inserted text> 
pdflatex.exe>                 }
pdflatex.exe> l.40   \end{TheMatrix}
```

I have no idea why the system assumes there's abracket missing and how to find out what actually went wrong. I've tried to turn on some additional tracing with

```
\tracinggroups=1
\tracingnesting=2
```

but I have no idea how to get any meaning from the output. What is going on here and how do I debug things like this?

Comment: There could be some trickery to build up a `\BODY`-like macro from the CSV contents and to parse that afterwards inside a `\matrix`, but maybe another approach instead of `\matrix` is preferrable?

Comment: I don't know why but adding double backslash (I don't know how to write it here) before `\end{TheMatrix}` worked for me.

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm I've converted the comment in answer to better show what I did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a CSV approach with some trickery. The CSV file is read and its content put inside a macro `\BODY`. This `\BODY` is used inside the matrix later.

This may not work, if the CSV content contains macros or umlauts since everything is expanded before it is added to `\BODY`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{csvsimple,etoolbox}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{filecontents*}{mystuff.csv}
mynode;mytext
n1;Hello
n2;World
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

% working example
\begin{tikzpicture}[every matrix/.style = {column sep = 0.8 cm, row sep = 0.2 cm}]
  \matrix{
    \draw (0,0) circle (4mm); & \node (n1) {Hello}; \\
    \draw (0,0) circle (2mm); & \node (n2) {world}; \\
  };
  \draw[thick, draw=black] (n1) -- (n2);
\end{tikzpicture}

% this works as well
\NewEnviron{TheMatrix}{\matrix[ampersand replacement=\&]{\BODY};}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every matrix/.style = {column sep = 0.8 cm, row sep = 0.2 cm}]
  \begin{TheMatrix}
    \draw (0,0) circle (4mm); \& \node (n1) {Hello}; \\ 
    \draw (0,0) circle (2mm); \& \node (n2) {world}; \\ 
  \end{TheMatrix}
  \draw[thick, draw=black] (n1) -- (n2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\def\BODY{}
% now let's try it from a CSV file
\begin{tikzpicture}[every matrix/.style = {column sep = 0.8 cm, row sep = 0.2 cm}]
  \csvreader[separator = semicolon, head to column names]{mystuff.csv}{}{
    \eappto\BODY{\noexpand\draw (0,0) circle (4mm); \noexpand\& \noexpand\node (\mynode) {\mytext}; \noexpand\\}
  }
  \matrix[ampersand replacement=\&]{\BODY};
  \draw[thick, draw=black] (n1) -- (n2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer, but I didn't know how to include `\\` inside a comment. I've inserted `\\` before `\end{TheMatrix}` in last example and worked. Why? I've no idea, just luck.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{filecontents*}{mystuff.csv}
mynode;mytext
n1;Hello
n2;World
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

% working example
\begin{tikzpicture}[every matrix/.style = {column sep = 0.8 cm, row sep = 0.2 cm}]
  \matrix{
    \draw (0,0) circle (4mm); & \node (n1) {Hello}; \\
    \draw (0,0) circle (2mm); & \node (n2) {world}; \\
  };
  \draw[thick, draw=black] (n1) -- (n2);
\end{tikzpicture}

% this works as well
\NewEnviron{TheMatrix}{\matrix[ampersand replacement=\&]{\BODY};}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every matrix/.style = {column sep = 0.8 cm, row sep = 0.2 cm}]
  \begin{TheMatrix}
    \draw (0,0) circle (4mm); \& \node (n1) {Hello}; \\        
    \draw (0,0) circle (2mm); \& \node (n2) {world}; \\        
  \end{TheMatrix} 
  \draw[thick, draw=black] (n1) -- (n2);
\end{tikzpicture}

% now let's try it from a CSV file
\begin{tikzpicture}[every matrix/.style = {column sep = 0.8 cm, row sep = 0.2 cm}]
  \begin{TheMatrix}
    \csvreader[separator = semicolon, head to column names]{mystuff.csv}{}{
      \draw (0,0) circle (4mm); \& \node (\mynode) {\mytext}; \\        
    }\\  %<------------------- This is what I added
  \end{TheMatrix} 
  \draw[thick, draw=black] (n1) -- (n2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Seems, I have underestimated the combination of `environ` and the TikZ parser :-)

Comment: Still, one double-backslash is too much. But, maybe, it is silently discarded.

Comment: This approach works for the simplified example, but for some reason it fails in my real-life document. Thanks for finding another workaround though.