# Is there any way to import Large matrices to LaTeX?

Tags: macros, matrices, import, shortcut

I'm sometimes dealing with matrices up till 20*20 - Is there a way to import these into LaTeX rather than manually typing them via the **\begin{matrix}** command?

The matrices are usually constructed in MATLAB or Maple - No luck on extracting them from there so far.

So far I have been making screendumps and inserting them as figures, but I would like to utilize the matrix-framework provided in LaTex.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: import from what? many systems will export their matrices in latex syntax, matlab. mathematica, R etc or just output a csv file and let latex read it via datatool or similar or ...

Comment: How is the matrix stored? In a simple text file? What does the matrix contain? Just numbers, symbols, or even entire math formulas? Are the cells separated by whitespace, commas, ampersands, or something else?

Comment: The short answer is yes but we need a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) showing what your matrices look like, both in terms of the input *and* the expected output.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/224415/build-pgf-tikz-matrix-from-csv-file, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146716/importing-csv-file-into-latex-as-a-table, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54990/convert-numpy-array-into-tabular

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution, and as it turns out, it was a quite simple on - so I thought I would share it with you.

MATLAB lets you convert any matrix into LaTeX code by using following command:

**In MATLAB**

Latex_Matrix = latex(sym(A))

where A is your defined matrix.

**In Maple** 
Execute your matrix, right-click the result then "Conversions->LaTeX".

The result should be ready LaTeX code.